# Designing a class in java for causing deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java learning the concepts of threading in java , i was planing to answer the following below questions

```
class Deadlocker 
{ 
void  executedByThreadOne(); 
void  executedByThreadTwo(); 
}
```

Provide  simple implementation of class Deadlocker above such that if the two methods are called concurrently by different  threads, there will be chance of a deadlock.
folks please advise how such can we design class in java

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to do your homework for you. If you have a specific problem with the task, tell us what you have tried so far and why it doesn't work. You can edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

Read some literature on deadlocks and think about, how to achieve this in a fake environment.

As a hint, you will propably need Thread.sleep to have your locks "overlapping". Imagine your locking process like an "x". Thread 1 is locking A, then sleeps, then locking B. But, while Thread 1 is sleeping, Thread B has to lock B and then try to lock A (which is already locked by A). Then you have your deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

One source that can cause deadlock are locks. If you call method1 from one thread and method2 from the other, there will be a big chance of getting a deadlock:

```
Object lock1 = ...;
Object lock2 = ... ;

public void method1(){
synchronized (lock1) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        synchronized (lock2) {
            System.out.println("Acquired both locks");
        }
    }
}
public void method2(){  
     synchronized (lock2) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
         synchronized (lock1) {
            System.out.println("Acquired both locks");
         }
     }
}
```

The above illustrates what is known as **lock‐ordering deadlocks**.